# S3 CompleteMultipartUpload fails after successful upload of each part

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm having trouble getting (low level) multipart uploads working today to Amazon S3, though it's been working essentially flawless for many, many months. In the last day or so it's started failing. I had a queue of 80+ file uploads that were fine until after about 60 files, and then it failed more often than it succeeded. Since then, even single file queues have failed.

I'm using essentially the same code as in in the low-level multipart upload examples in the docs, except with a do-while loop that will retry uploading a single part if it fails. Only successful part uploads are added to a List, which is latter added as part of the CompleteMultipartUploadRequest.

Though none of the part uploads ever fail though; only the CompleteMultipartUploadRequest that is sent following all the part uploads. This is the only exception I've seen on every failure, and it always stems from the CompleteMultipartUpload request.

I even wrapped the CompleteMultipartUpload object creation and request in a loop to in case it was an issue with S3 being "ready" to concatenate the parts together, but even a progressive backoff period with significant time delays didn't help.

```
Exception: Maximum number of retry attempts reached : 3
Exception: at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.pauseOnRetry(Int32 retries, Int32 maxRetries, HttpStatusCode status, String requestAddr, WebHeaderCollection headers, Exception cause)
   at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.handleRetry(S3Request userRequest, HttpWebRequest request, WebHeaderCollection respHdrs, Int64 orignalStreamPosition, Int32 retries, HttpStatusCode statusCode, Exception cause)
   at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.getResponseCallback[T](IAsyncResult result)
   at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.endOperation[T](IAsyncResult result)
   at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.EndCompleteMultipartUpload(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.CompleteMultipartUpload(CompleteMultipartUploadRequest request)
```

and this is the code below. Any suggestions on what could be wrong?

```
// List to store upload part responses.
List<UploadPartResponse> uploadResponses = new List<UploadPartResponse>();
List<PartETag> uploadPartETags = new List<PartETag>();

// 1. Initialize.
InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initiateRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest()
    .WithBucketName(s3bucketName)
    .WithKey(key);
initResponse = s3Client.InitiateMultipartUpload(initiateRequest);
bwLogUploadFiles("multipart upload ID " + initResponse.UploadId);


// 2. Upload Parts.
uploadFileSize = new FileInfo(sourceFilepath).Length;
uploadTypicalPartSize = PART_SIZE_DEFAULT;      // 5 MB

uploadNumParts = uploadFileSize / uploadTypicalPartSize + 1;
Debug.WriteLine("# of parts: " + uploadNumParts);

int retryCount = 0;

long filePosition = 0;
for (int i = 1; filePosition < uploadFileSize; i++)
{
    uploadCurrentPart = i;

    //long percent = (100 * filePosition) / uploadFileSize;
    //reportUploadProgress((int)percent, filePosition);

    bwLogUploadFiles("upload part " + i + " of " + uploadNumParts);

    retryCount = 0;

    // make the part size exactly equal to the lesser of the part size (5MB) or the remaining amount
    //long tmpPartSize = Math.Min(uploadTypicalPartSize, (uploadFileSize - filePosition));      

    // per documentation examples, just make part size the same every time, even if remaining file length is bigger
    long tmpPartSize = uploadTypicalPartSize;

    // Create request to upload a part.
    UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest()
        .WithBucketName(s3bucketName)
        .WithKey(key)
        .WithUploadId(initResponse.UploadId)
        .WithPartNumber(i)
        .WithPartSize(tmpPartSize)
        .WithFilePosition(filePosition)
        .WithFilePath(sourceFilepath)
        .WithSubscriber(transferUtilityUploadSubscriberLowLevel)
        .WithReadWriteTimeout(PART_TIMEOUT)
        .WithTimeout(UPLOAD_TIMEOUT);


    UploadPartResponse resp = null;

    // repeat the part upload until it succeeds.
    Boolean anotherPass;  
    do
    {
        anotherPass = false;  // assume everythings ok
        try {
            // Upload part
            resp = s3Client.UploadPart(uploadRequest);

            // add response to our list.
            uploadResponses.Add(resp);

            // only creating PartETag and adding to a list for testing a different way of constructing the CompleteMultipartUploadRequest at the end.
            PartETag petag = new PartETag(resp.PartNumber, resp.ETag);
            uploadPartETags.Add(petag);

            bwLogUploadFiles("upload part " + resp.PartNumber + " of " + uploadNumParts + " success. Part ETag "+resp.ETag);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            anotherPass = true; // repeat
            retryCount++;
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message +": retry part #" + i);
            bwLogUploadFiles("upload part " + i + " of " + uploadNumParts + " FAIL.  Will retry if attempt #" + retryCount + "<"uploading part #"+i+" couldn't upload after "+MAX_RETRIES+" attempts.  Upload failed");

    filePosition += tmpPartSize;


}
//reportUploadProgress(100, uploadFileSize);


// Step 3: complete.

Boolean retryCompleteRequest = true;
Boolean completeSuccess = false;
int  completeAttempts = 0;
const int delaySecondsMultiple = 3;


// retry a few times in case it's just a timing or S3 sync or readiness issue.  Maybe giving it some time make following the part uploads will do the trick
do
{
    retryCompleteRequest = false;
    try
    {
        bwLogUploadFiles("complete the multipart upload, attempt #"+(completeAttempts+1) );
        if (completeAttempts >0)
        {
            bwLogUploadFiles("delay " + (delaySecondsMultiple * completeAttempts) + " seconds");
            Thread.Sleep(delaySecondsMultiple * 1000 * completeAttempts);       // 
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("now complete the Mulitpart Upload Request");
        CompleteMultipartUploadRequest completeRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest()
            .WithBucketName(s3bucketName)
            .WithKey(key)
            .WithUploadId(initResponse.UploadId)
            //.WithPartETags(uploadResponses)   // historically we've been attaching a List<UploadPartResponse> 
            .WithPartETags(uploadPartETags);    // for testing we're trying List<PartETag>

        CompleteMultipartUploadResponse completeUploadResponse = s3Client.CompleteMultipartUpload(completeRequest);
        completeSuccess = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        completeAttempts++;
        retryCompleteRequest = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred: {0}", e.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);

        bwLogUploadFiles("Exception: " + e.Message);
        bwLogUploadFiles("Exception: " + e.StackTrace);
    }
}
while (retryCompleteRequest && completeAttempts < MAX_RETRIES);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is something not logical but you can try it for this exception.
Try to explicitly set s3Client Protocol to HTTP.